# Web Scraping com R - tabela estática

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

Gostaria de consolidar os dados de um site de aposta em uma base de dados no `R`.

Estou tentando da forma abaixo, mas meu script não reconhece as colunas e linhas da tabela de fato, apenas o layout:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)   
        

url_base <- "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/copa-do-brasil-2020/results/"

site <- read_html(url_base)

info_ajuste_HTML <- html_nodes(site, "table")

info_ajuste <- html_text(info_ajuste_HTML)
  
lista_tabela <- site %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Preciso das seguintes informações:

1. Nome dos times
2. Pontuação final do jogo
3. Probabilidades

Alguma sabe me dizer como resolver?

Comment: Olá Sarah, poderia por favor incluir na pergunta qual é o erro que aparece para você? E mostrar um exemplo do `data.frame` que você precisa?